# Assembly cross references lost when manually loading assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I just came across an issue with assembly references I haven't seen before. In my usual production code, my loader application loads the main application assembly (and other references) by passing the raw bytes to `Assembly.Load` and then calling the entry point.

Today I needed to have the main application dynamically load another reference (henceforth called the 'dll'), which contains a class that inherits from a base class in the main program. This works fine when running the main application directly. When running it through the loader, the main application loads the dll just fine, but it doesn't seem to know that the currently loaded main application is the same as the one the dll references. So casting to the base class obviously won't work. And I'm stuck.

I'm assuming the main application assembly is losing it's identity somehow.

Here's some code that illustrates the issue:

```
// main application
namespace Program1
{
    public class BaseClass { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            string s = "Library1.Class1, Library1";            
            var t = Type.GetType( s, true );
            Debug.Assert( t.IsSubclassOf( typeof( BaseClass ) ) );
        }
    }    
}

// dll
namespace Library1
{
    public class Class1 : Program1.BaseClass { }
}

// loader
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes( "Program1.exe" );
        var asm = Assembly.Load( bytes );
        var e = asm.EntryPoint;
        e.Invoke( null, new object[] { null } );
    }
}
```

When running Program1 directly it works, when running it through the loader the assert fails.

So, could anyone explain what's going on here - and if there is a possible way around it?

Comment: Have you checked the Fusion logs?

Comment: @JfBeaulac Didn't occur to me, but had I done it, i'd certainly would have seen it loading an assembly twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (let's call dllA and dllB your libraries), dllA has a reference to dllB and you load dllA and it doesn't crashes it means .net has autoresolved and loaded dllB.

Then when you load again dllB it's another assembly, and then the types don't match, I ran myself a lot of times with that situation with a dll-loading system, at the end is better to add the referenced libraries (in this case dllB) in the .exe folder and let the system load it automatically when you load dllA.

Another option if you need the reference to the library is to attach to the AssemblyResolve event before loading DllA, then when you load it the event will fire requiring you to load DllB and thus you can store the reference to the library.

Comment: AssemblyResolve: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ah, hell, that seems really obvious now. Didn't think that obviously the dll would load what it needed by itself. All pretty funny, because in production I already use AssemblyResolve to load encrypted assemblies that have changed file names (hence no auto-resolve), so had I ran it as in production, it'd have worked. But now I ran it with the files all there for it to find. Thanks a bunch man.

Comment: Hehehe, that error is a pain until you find what it caused it, and that's an omfg moment.. XD

Comment: Very much omfg indeed!